# CDbConnection error in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

Whenever I am trying to login in my Yii application it is showing error like

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver .
```

I googled many hours and from many blogs I knew that I need pdo_mysql but that is already installed. In php.ini I also made comment these lines

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

and restarted apache server but still showing  the same prob. I am using ubuntu 11.04. Please help me to solve the error.

Comment: Try to check `phpinfo();`. You should see there PDO drivers supported. Ubuntu package `php5-mysql` provides necessary libraries.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to MySQL or another kind of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu(linux), you will need to recompile Apache.  Simple uncommenting will not work.
In Ubuntu, I believe you can do some apt-get.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` followed by `sudo apache2ctl graceful` worked for me on Ubuntu Desktop

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why you have the first line commented, you should UNCOMMENT

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

and restart the apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have

```
sudo apt install php-xml php-mbstring php-pdo php-mysql
```

installed, and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

My solution was related to caching:

```
cache' => array(
    'class' => 'system.caching.CDbCache',
    //'class' => 'system.caching.CFileCache',
    'connectionID'=>'db', // <<< THIS IS THE ISSUE
),
```

if connectionID is not set, db caching defaults to mysqli database in /protected/data directory which cannot be accessed if mysqli driver is not installed on system (common issue with dedicated servers, DO droplets, xampp/wamp...) or, you can disable db caching and enable fileCache instead.